# How to store data from hdfs to accumulo?

Tags: java, hdfs, cloudera, accumulo

I am involved in one POC, which will take data from HDFS and store it to apache accumulo. I have gone through various articles, but didn't find any possible solution.

Looking for guidance in this regard.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [the importtsv command from Apache HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#importtsv), but for Accumulo?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you missed the [Java Apidocs](https://accumulo.apache.org/1.8/apidocs/) and the section in the Accumulo User Manual on [Writing Accumulo Clients](https://accumulo.apache.org/1.8/accumulo_user_manual.html#_writing_accumulo_clients).

I also guess you missed the integrations with other related software projects like [Apache Pig](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/func.html#AccumuloStorage), [Apache Hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AccumuloIntegration), and [Presto](https://github.com/bloomberg/presto-accumulo).

edit: sorry this came off a lot nastier than it should have been -- I would encourage you to read the docs more thoroughly in advance before asking such generic questions like this in the future.